# Can I answer questions on Stack Overflow and promote my website link?

Tags: discussion, answers, external-links, self-promotion

If I answer the technical questions with a full clear explanation of the whole concept, and at the end of my answer leave the link to my website, is that okay? Is it fine to promote your website by answering technical questions? My website is a tech support platform for debugging help via voice chat and screen sharing.

Comment: No, that is considered spamming.

Comment: No, you can [advertise](http://stackexchange.com/mediakit), but not spam

Comment: Nope, that's regarded spam. What you can do is advertise your business in your profile.

Comment: For the record, you totally did the right thing by asking here first. The downvotes are likely to mean "no, you can't do this here". They do not reflect badly on your reputation score.

Answer (score 8):

No, linking to your site from your answers to promote it is not permitted and considered spam.

When moderators come across accounts that appear to be using their answers to promote a site or service, we send the following (private) message:

> We noticed that a substantial proportion of your posts seem to exist only to promote your product or website. Per the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior):
>
> > Be careful, because the community frowns on overt self-promotion and
> >     tends to vote it down and flag it as spam. Post good, relevant
> >     answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or
> >     website, so be it. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in
> >     your answers. Also, if a huge percentage of your posts include a
> >     mention of your product or website, you're probably here for the wrong
> >     reasons. Our advertising rates are quite reasonable; contact our ad
> >     sales team for details.
>
> Any type of "astroturfing" promotion is not acceptable.  It brings
>   down the overall value of genuine recommendations for everyone on the
>   site.
>
> If you can stay within the above guidelines, and offer questions and
>   answers of genuine benefit to the community which happen to mention
>   your affiliation or product in context -- and with full disclosure --
>   then your future contributions are welcome.

We also clean up the content; remove the posts altogether or if the answer itself is of value without the promotional parts, edit the post to remove those.

Comment: Currently I am wondering "How about comments promising a working sample and linking to the poster's own website?" Because someone posted such a comment on one of my answers (and another comment with the same content on the question to which it belongs)

Comment: @0X0nosugar: I see what you mean. Yes, that's rather spammy, I'll clean that up.